# Mutliple spaces/desktops: Disable switching to other spaces when opening an app?

Tags: desktop, spaces, mission-control

Not sure if I explained it well but you know when you have multiple spaces, you will still see the opened app on that other space on the app drawer on the bottom. I hate how it makes my desktop cluttered. There's a reason why I separated that space.

I work multiple jobs so I assign different spaces for it. I want that space to act as its own desktop. Like if I open Finder, it will open a new Finder window on that space and not take me to the space where there's an opened finder app :(

Answer (score 0):

System Prefs > Mission Control > When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for that application
-Uncheck.

[image]